# Keep duplicate values and remove from list

Tags: google-sheets, google-sheets-formula

I am aware in Microsoft Excel, we can use `Conditional Formatting` to highlight and find duplicate values.

Essentially, in Google Sheets what I want to do is using a second list - find all the values in the first list that are the same as the second and then only keep duplicates.

For example, in [my google sheet](https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1zDZl910UQcTDbfOdDXh4cNMLzi0Xy5zK2-dY4A6B4GM/edit?usp=sharing) I have the original list as:

```
Shoe Brand  Location
Nike    USA
Adidas  Europe
Lacoste Europe
Ralph Lauren    USA
Under Armour    USA
Umbro   USA
Puma    Europe
Slazenger   Europe
Timberlands USA
Crocs   USA
CK  USA
```

Then the second list in the [same Google sheet](https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1zDZl910UQcTDbfOdDXh4cNMLzi0Xy5zK2-dY4A6B4GM/edit?usp=sharing) has this:

```
Shoe Brand  Location
Lacoste Europe
Timberlands USA
Slazenger   Europe
Nike    USA
Crocs   USA
```

Effectively, I only want to keep the shoes that appear in the second list

Thanks

Comment: What is the question here? What code have you already tried implementing?

Answer (score 1):

If I understood well, you want to create a new table that compare your first and second tables, and keep only the duplicated shoes (i.e. any shoe that is in the second table but not in the first should be ignored)

You can therefore try something like this:

```
= ARRAYFORMULA(SORT(IFNA(UNIQUE(VLOOKUP(F2:F,A2:B, {1,2}, 0)),""),1,0))
```

[image]